# Querying with function on Flask-SQLAlchemy model gives BaseQuery object is not callable error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to query services between two dates and sum their prices. When I try to use `func.sum` with `Services.query`, I get `TypeError: BaseQuery object is not callable`. How do I query using a function with Flask-SQLAlchemy?

```
Services.query(func.sum(Services.price)).filter(Services.dateAdd.between(start, end))
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`Model.query` is a shortcut to `db.session.query(Model)`, it's not callable. If you're not querying a model, continue to use `db.session.query(...)` as you would with regular SQLAlchemy.

```
db.session.query(db.func.sum(Services.price)).filter(
    Services.dateAdd.between(start, end)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

fwiw after this long time, you can use Flask-SQLAlchemy syntax by using:

```
Services.query(func.sum(Services.price)).filter(Services.dateAdd.between(start, end)).scalar()  # or you can use .scalar() ; .one() ; .first() ; .all() depending on what you want to achieve
```

Basically, syntax `Model.query(...).filter(...)` needs to end with what you want to get. This is what is missing from your query generating the error.

[Query object in SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html)