# Flask, SQLAlchemy: how to use wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField for dropdowns

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask/SQLAlchemy.  I have a database with two tables:  Family and Chart.  The Family table has two columns: id and familyname.  The Chart table has several columns including industry.  I was able to display the dropdown for Family/family field, but not the dropdown for Chart/industry field.  Here is my code and would appreciate the help.

forms.py

```
from flask import request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError, DataRequired, Length
from app.models import Family, Chart

def family_query():
    return Family.query.order_by('familyname asc').all()
def industry_query():
    return Chart.query(Chart.industry.distinct()).all()
class FamilyForm(FlaskForm):
    optsFamily = QuerySelectField(query_factory=family_query,allow_blank=True, get_label='familyname',  blank_text="Click to select")
    optsIndustry = QuerySelectField(query_factory=industry_query,allow_blank=True, get_label='industry',  blank_text="Click to select")
```

routes.py

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, g,current_app
from app import db
from app.main.forms import FamilyForm
from app.models import Family, Chart
from app.main import bp

@bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = FamilyForm()
    return render_template('index.html', form = form )
```

HTML

```
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.optsFamily }}
     <ul>
      {% for error in form.optsFamily.errors %}
      <li style="color:red;">{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
   </ul>
    {{ form.optsIndustry }}  
    <ul>
      {% for error in form.optsIndustry.errors %}
      <li style="color:red;">{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

Comment: There should've been an error and you should always include errors with their tracebacks in debugging questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying with function on Flask-SQLAlchemy model gives BaseQuery object is not callable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918479/querying-with-function-on-flask-sqlalchemy-model-gives-basequery-object-is-not-c)

Comment: The error I got was related to app being aborted but didn't get a message explaining the reason.

Answer (score 0):

got it.  I updated the query as folllows:

```
def industry_query():
    return Chart.query.order_by('industry asc').distinct('industry').all()
```