# flask sqlalchemy query with keyword as function argument

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am stuck with a query in a function. here is my code:
    `def action(changePin, action):
        pins = Pins.query.all()
        changePin = int(changePin)
        deviceName = Pins.query.filter_by(pin=changePin, name)
        if action == "on":
            GPIO.output(changePin, GPIO.HIGH)
            print("turned ", deviceName , " on")
        if action =="off":
            GPIO.output(changePin, GPIO.LOW)
            print("turned ", deviceName , " off")
        for pin in pins:
            db.session.commit()`

The error for this is

```
 File "<stdin>", line 4
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

In line 4 I want to find the name of the pin relating to the pin "changePin", this is adapted code from a tutorial, here is the origional code where a dictionary holds the pin information not a database, code:

```
deviceName = pins[changePin]['name']
```

I have tried numerous different ways but none work, here is a list of the different versions of line 4:

```
deviceName = Pins.query.filter_by(changePin=pin).name
deviceName = Pins.query.filter_by(changePin, name=name)
deviceName = Pins.query.filter_by(Pins.pin=changePin, Pins.Name)
deviceName = Pins.query(Pins.pin=changePin, Pins.Name)
deviceName = Pins.query(**changePin, Pins.name)
deviceName = Pins.query(**changePin)
deviceName = db.session.filter_by(Pins.changePin)
deviceName = db.session(Pins).filter_by(pin=changePin)
```

and many other variations, I have read the sqlalchemy docs and the flask docs, but I have not seen any comparisons, I have looked at and tried this; [flask sqlalchemy query with keyword as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506105/flask-sqlalchemy-query-with-keyword-as-variable?lq=1)
but got this;

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in action
TypeError: BaseQuery object argument after ** must be a mapping, not int`

this is my models.py code;

```
class Pins(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
pin = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, unique=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(64))
upDown = db.Column(db.String(4))
state = db.Column(db.String(9))

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Valves {}>'.format(self.pin)
```

[Querying with function on Flask-SQLAlchemy model gives BaseQuery object is not callable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918479/)

Dear Menno
Thank you for comming back to me I have followed your advice and it works!!!

```
rows = Pins.query.filter_by(pin=changePin).all()
deviceName = rows[0].name
```

I don't understand how the "rows[0].name" part works but it does, 
thank you thank you

help
regards
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filter_by expression selects *rows*, not fields. From the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_2/orm/query.html?highlight=filter_by#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by): "apply the given filtering criterion to a copy of this Query, using keyword expressions.". `Name` is not a keyword expression, just a name.

Also, after building the query, you have to run it. You do that by calling `all()` on it:

> deviceName = Pins.query.filter_by(pin=changePin).all()

Letś also change the name of the outcome:

> rows = Pins.query.filter_by(pin=changePin).all()

Calling that returns a list with zero or more rows, hence the name. `rows[0]` (the first row) is what you want. After you have a row, a field becomes an attribute of the row: `rows[0].name`. You can also use `one()` to get a *unique* row.

If you still need that: To limit the columns that are returned use [load only cols](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_2/orm/loading_columns.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!! I have not understood your reply, but I have looked at the  "load only cols" and changed my code to '  deviceName = db.session.query(Pins).options(load_only("state")) ' there are no error messages but  this prints "turned  SELECT pins.id AS pins_id, pins.state AS pins_state 
FROM pins  off " the pin changes state but I want the associated name to be printed. I do not understand enough to know how to express myself in the question!!

Comment: What is printed is the query that SQLAlchemy wants to send to the database. Superhandy for debugging, just not what you want ;=). I applied my recipe to your original code. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Dear Menno, Thank you for clarifying your first answer, as you can see I have posted my new code into My question and it works. I did not understand that the '.all() ' calls the query, and in the second part rows[0].name works for all rows in the database not just the first. Finally does this mean that the results of "rows = Pins.query.filter_by(pin=changePin).all()" is a dictionary? Kind regards Paul

Comment: From the SQLAlchemy documentation: "Return the results represented by this Query as a list.". So no, not a dictionary, but a list.